# Does clustering an index in PostgreSQL take advantage of preordered data?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I create a table like so:

```
SELECT t1.c1, t2.c2, t3.c3, *several more columns*
INTO t4
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.j2 = t2.j2
INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.j3 = t3.j3;
```

Then, I create a clustered primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE t4 ADD CONSTRAINT pk_t4 PRIMARY KEY (c1, c2, c3);
CLUSTER t4 USING pk_t4;
```

If I add an `ORDER BY c1, c2, c3` clause to the `SELECT INTO` query, will that speed up the clustering of the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are creating a new table with `SELECT ... INTO` or `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...`, PostgreSQL will insert records as they are ordered.

Therefore, yes, if you add an `ORDER BY c1, c2, c3`, which are also a primary key, they will already be clustered, so there will be no need for `CLUSTER`.

However, if you run cluster again, I think PostgreSQL will rewrite the table.

---

**Example**

First generate a table with 5 million ints, with random order:

```
testdb=> create table clust as select a from generate_series(1, 5000000) a order by random() ;
SELECT 5000000
Time: 14675,540 ms
testdb=> create index clust_a_idx on clust (a);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 13145,245 ms
testdb=> cluster clust using clust_a_idx;
CLUSTER
Time: 19126,597 ms
testdb=> cluster clust using clust_a_idx;
CLUSTER
Time: 7968,350 ms
```

Clustering the first time takes 19 seconds, the second time 7.9 seconds.

Create another table, this time already ordered:

```
testdb=> create table clust2 as select a from generate_series(1, 5000000) a ;
SELECT 5000000
Time: 2612,878 ms
testdb=> create index clust2_a_idx on clust2 (a);
CREATE INDEX
Time: 6816,040 ms
testdb=> cluster clust2 using clust2_a_idx;
CLUSTER
Time: 7762,115 ms
testdb=> cluster clust2 using clust2_a_idx;
CLUSTER
Time: 7861,405 ms
```

Clustering already ordered table takes about 7.8 seconds to cluster.

Does `ORDER BY c1, c2, c3` help? **Yes.**

But if you insert with correct order, the table is already ordered (clustered) and `CLUSTER` is redundant.

Comment: Thank you, @hruske. Does PostgreSQL mark the table or key as clustered so it can use that information in its query plan or is clustering no more than ordering?

Comment: Clustering is arranging heap (table) according to index sort order. Lookups via index still require index lookup, the most benefit with cluster is when you have an access pattern, which has high probability of touching neighboring records, which is when postgres will need to fetch less pages, since they will already be in memory.